# Red Pitaya DC Offsets calibration don't seems to work

Tags: redpitaya

Was wondering if anyone familiar with the Red Pitaya had successfully calibrated the DC offsets.

You should be able to acquire a "baseline" on any channel, calculate the negative average of the values and apply these to the DC offset values of the EEPROM vector using the calib -w command.

I have tried this it has no effect on the data received by the acquire command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Received an email from my local reseller of the RedPitaya and recommended to set DC offset using the calib -w command. Which is exactly what I was doing, but doesn't work. To get around it, I measured the baseline in my software took the average and applied the offset to signal. Not as elegant as I wished. If anyone has been able to get this to work, please comment.

Comment: I would expect this to get better attention at electronics.stackexchange.com. Perhaps try posting there?

Comment: Thanks... that could be why.

Answer (score 1):

A detail buried in the 2018 [Red Pitaya Developers guide](https://redpitaya.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developerGuide/software/clt.html#signal-acquisition-utility) is that …

> The signal from Red Pitaya can be acquired through the **acquire command line utility**. It will return **raw samples** from the ADC buffer to standard output, **with no calibration compensation**.